# QGIS make line attribute

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3

How to automatically load all my attribute values into a layer after manually adding an attribute field? Or how to achieve the effect of PointConnector plugin in a more flexible that retains attributes?

I have a point table

> City | Lat | Long

and a route table with an attribute

> From | To | Journeys

After loading both files in QGIS, I use the PointConnector plugin to generate lines connecting the cities, however the resulting layer lacks the *Journeys* Source Field (which I would use to determine a graduated line color in the Symbology pane).

I can add the Source Field manually, and enter each and every *Journeys* value in the Attribute Table of the layer. This becomes a challenge when I have 1000s of data points.

Can you advise a viable solution?

I suppose the PointConnector plugin doesn't support importing attributes. How can I automatically load all my *Journeys* attribute values after manually adding the attribute field?

How can I achieve the same effect offered by PointConnector (joining two points with a line) in another more flexible way that can make use of attributes in the import tables?

Comment: What exactly does the PointConnector plugin do? Why don't you use tools already available in QGIS?

Answer (score 2):

By creating a new field "Fromto" (or any name) in your *route table* and in your *resulting layer*. This new field will contain both 'From' and 'To' (example: From: "Paris", to:"Moscow" --> Fromto: 'ParisMoscow').

You will then be able to add a **Vector Join** in your *resulting layer* and connect it to 
*route table* on their attributes "Fromto". the *resulting layer* will take each matching connection and add the route table fields to its table.